# Is there C# shorthand to cast a value to its method's return type?

Tags: c#, shorthand

Is there shorthand in C# for casting a value to its method's return type? For example, in this method, is there a shorthand way to cast the return value of GetInt's to its return type of 'int', instead of discretely typing out 'int'?

I know this is a really simple example, and many of you are going to say "it's easier to just put (int) there" but it would be really great syntactic sugar for some things I'm trying to do if this is possible. It would be very similar to the 'default' keyword shorthand that already exists.

```
// Return type of SomeFunc cannot be changed by me
object SomeFunc();

public int GetInt()
{
    object Value = SomeFunc();
    // I know "Value" should be of type "int" here.
    return ({ReturnType})Value;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a sane way. But I can think of two different *insane* ways of doing it: (1) Reflection + Delegate properties + `System.Linq.Expressions`, and (2) a Generic class with Delegate as ctor parameter + Get method.

Comment: Why use `object` in the first place? If you know the type, why not store it using the actual type?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It matters. Yes, you could just cast. Even better, store the value using the correct type. Perhaps use a generic class so you don't have to use `object` at all. If you wanted to convert between custom classes instead of `object` you could add implicit or explicit cast operators to the types

Comment: Note that when an implicit conversion exists (as should normally be the case in this scenario) then you don't need a cast at all. Which is probaly why: No, such a language feature does not exist.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I said in my question, I know the example I gave is very simple, and in the example putting "(int)" would be easiest, but my question is not about the example I gave, it is whether such a feature exists. Ignore the example I put in the question, it is not the issue I am asking about.

Comment: @user3163495 post a realistic example then. There *are* implicit casts. If there was an implicit cast between the return type and the actual value you wouldn't need a cast at all. You can create an implicit cast operator for a new type. An *object* though, can't be implicitly converted to anything else. How could a string or `Image` be cast to an `int?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's not necessary, because my question isn't to get your opinion on whether I should be doing this.

Comment: @user3163495 on the contrary, it's very important. Again, if you could use an implicit cast you wouldn't need such a feature. Why can't you use an implicit cast? Because you used the most restrictive type possible in that respect - object can't be implicitly cast to anything else. The compiler simply doesn't have enough information to decide if the cast is safe or not

Comment: @user3163495 so, given that what you want is already available with a far broader context (`double d=3` is valid), when enough type info is available, what's the actual problem here? Why go through `object`? What if `Value` is `"potato"`?

Comment: Q `Is there shorthand in C# for casting a value to its method's return type?` A `No`.

Comment: FWIW, this question should not have been closed. **It is crystal clear**. It's just that C# does not have this feature. In fact, the only language I know of that has this feature is Jai (autocast via `xx`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does such a feature exist? **None that I am aware of.**

Can you add such syntactic sugar somehow?
**Probably yes**, but none of the options are going to be simpler than an explicit cast. You may lose some IDE features. You'll probably go against good practices. I imagine that things like **Reflection, Decorators, dynamic types, switch expressions**, etc may be of use here.

*Implicit conversions?* You can always use a derived class implicitly converted to any of its base class. Some helpful links - [casting-and-type-conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions), [user-defined-conversion-operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators), [type-testing-and-cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast)

If you are sure that your object is castable safely, you can use alternate syntax which **doesn't throw an exception**, `Value as int`

At the end of the day, none of this needs to be considered first, unless one has a use case where it could help them **BIG TIME**. Syntactic sugar is not even close to that use case IMO, especially for a **statically typed** language.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of using generics (it won't work with int, but will with custom type):

```cs
public class Foo { }

public static object Value = null;
public static T GetFoo<T>() where T : Foo
{
    return (T)Value;
}
```

Comment: How is this any different than `(int)Value` or `(int?)Value` ?

Comment: Well. You can give as Foo not an exact type but rather base type. What I meant maybe a concept of generics could be worth looking at in the topicstarter's case.